# Using select2 typeahead with a url outside the web root

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-select2, typeahead.js

How can I get select2 to access a url outside the web root for a db query select?

I have this:

```
$('#payees').select2({
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    ajax: {
      url: "/connectors/search-connector.php",
      dataType: 'json',
      data: function (term, page) {
        return {
          q: term
        };
      },
      results: function (data, page) {
        return { results: data };
      }
    }
  });
```

I would like /connectors/search-connector.php to be actually outside the web root [not web accessible] ~ now I know I can do this with PHP, but select2 appends a querystring to the end of the url that needs to be somehow captured and passed.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can't access with javascript to php files if these are outside the web root or not are accessible from a public url.
Try create first a php with public URL and this file will call the private file